# Teradata SQL query limit rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query that return 2 million rows.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM dB.TABLE
LIMIT .....
```

I want to get 100000 rows trying my first query like get rows 1 to 100000. Then rewrite my query to pull next 100000. There are now column like Counter/Line Number in my table .. what are my options?

Comment: Why don't you want to get all 2,000,000 at once?

Comment: I have to upload the file to another server so It’s easier. 2m rows but many columns- so it’s fairly large in GB.

Comment: If you need to export to multiple files you should use TPT which can do that directly: https://docs.teradata.com/search/all?query=%2522Writing+Files+with+Multiple+Instances%2522

Comment: If your counter is simply a number between 1 and 2000000 then just add a where clause:  where counter <= 100000, where counter between 100001 and 200000, etc.

Comment: TPT or Fast Export (which I find a little easier to use).